# Proving ties with Europe and not only home country?

Tags: visas, usa, europe, f1-visas

To obtain a F1 (or any other non-immigrant visa) you have to give proof of ties with your home country.

I am a citizen of country A in Europe but currently studying (and working during the summer) in the UK. Can I tell the visa officer that I intend to go back to work in the UK (or any other country in Europe) after my study period, or do I necessarily have to convince him I will go back to country A? I could probably get a letter from my current employer saying they'd like for me to go back once I finish my education.

I have my parents and many friends in country A and probably going to go back there from time to time to visit them, but I don't necessarily plan to live or work there. Would that be frowned upon?

Comment: Normally, I would assume that this doesn't really matter as long as you can prove ties to the EU, where you have a working permission (by law and European contracts). But I neither know if this is what they formally look for, *nor* do I know whether the Brexit will make you unable to return to the UK for working, and the visa offer may know this, so this may weaken your case. Hence, this is only a comment. Also note that intending to return there is not the type of strong ties they look for.

Comment: If you are studying and working in the UK, then your country of residence would be the UK, and I would expect that to be the place you're supposed to show ties with, not wherever you were born or raised.

Comment: The [Department of State page on the subject](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/student-visa.html) says they "may request (...) evidence of (...) Your intent to depart the United States upon completion of the course of study". They probably don't care where you go, as long as you leave :-)